# Convert weird characters - Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

How can we convert with Ruby a string such as this one:

To:

```
Latorre
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = ""
 => "" 
s.unicode_normalize(:nfkc).capitalize
 => "Latorre"
```

Here is a great article about unicode normalization: https://blog.daftcode.pl/fixing-unicode-for-ruby-developers-60d7f6377388